# Finding duplicate texts in IEnumerable<TextBox> collection

Tags: c#, linq

I have a collection of textboxes in my winform application.

I need help with LINQ query to get the collection of TextBox (i.e. IEnumerable) which contain duplicate entries.I want to make use of LINQ.
This query I used, is returning just the duplicate entry. But I need all the duplicate entries.

```
var duplicates = emailAddressList.GroupBy(t => t.Text)
                        .Where(g => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(g.Key))
                        .SelectMany(grp => grp.Skip(1))
                        .ToList();
```

Can any one help where am I going wrong ?

Regards

Comment: Remove the SelectMany line. You will get a grouping of the text boxes by the contained text. I.e. you will have a list of { key: "Text", TextBox[] { all text boxes containing this text } }.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This query I used, is returning just the duplicate entry. But I need
>   all the duplicate entries.

Check if `g.Count() > 1` and use `SelectMany(g => g)` to get all of each duplicate-group instead of only the duplicates (without first).

```
var duplicates = emailAddressList
  .GroupBy(t => t.Text)
  .Where(g => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(g.Key) && g.Count() > 1)
  .SelectMany(g => g)
  .ToList();
```